# How do you produce word document from latex sources and track changes

Tags: overleaf, texmaker, msword

I am writing my thesis in latex and since my advisor does not know tex, and only wants word document, I have a bit of a problem here

I am using Windows 7 and MS Word 2010 and I am writing my thesis using TexMaker (and have MikTex as backend) (and use Overleaf also, to quickly show my thesis to people)

Now, if I was using word, I could send my advisor the word document, he would activate track changes to make necessary edits in the document, and when I would get the document back, I could quickly look and accept this changes

Now I have 2 problems here, first is how to generate word document using TexMaker to send to my adivisor, and the second is, whats the best way to track his changes (I don't know if I can convert word document back to tex)

I hope someone has some good ideas

Thanks for Answering and Best Regards

Comment: Hi, welcome! Even if I am a very strong LaTeX defender and user, do yourself a favor and use word. You can sort-of do change management in LaTeX (with some source code tracker and a strong policy on how to write text), but if your advisor wants word, and you can't manage to change their mind, interoperability will be a nightmare.

Comment: Unless it is absolutely necessary (unlikely), just do it in Word directly. If the reason for using TeX is to create diagrams, you may be able to convert the TeX PDF diagram to a raster image (png), at very high density (resolution). Then place the image in your Word document, scaled to fit.